# Невступившее слитно или раздельно

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Постановление подается на невступившее в законную силу решение суда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Не вступившее" — раздельно.

***Постановление подается на не вступившее в законную силу решение суда.***

**Причастия с зависимыми словами** (за исключением наречий меры и степени) **пишутся раздельно** с отрицательной частицей "не".

Не вступившее (куда?) — в законную силу.

Примеры слиного/раздельного написания одного и того же причастия в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия зависимых слов:

1. Он сердито скомкал **непрочитанный** номер газеты и отбросил его (Н. Н. Шпанов. Старая тетрадь) — нет зависимых от причастия слов, пишем **слитно**.

2. Он отправился в кабинет, заперся там и, отключив телефоны, достал из стола длинный, еще **не прочитанный** свиток, который час назад доставили ему летучие мыши (Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и колодец Посейдона) — есть зависимое слово "ещё", пишем **раздельно**.